# Controling Pc Mouse from Gryoscope/Accelormeter

Tags: mouse, accelerometer, gyroscope

I have build an IMU consisting of an Accelerometer and Gyroscope that can provide 6DOF motion output results to pc. I use a serial COM port over USB interface to get data on pc and i can see the data through Hyper terminal. 
Now what i want to do is control my mouse pointer with that data for demonstration purposes. I initially looked at GlovePIe application but it doesn't support serial com ports. So it would be great if anybody could advice or direct me to a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing something similar, controlling pc mouse with android phone. But I am using Bluetooth and the touchscreen as input. You can look into win32 api functions for controlling com port.

You can also you sockets to send coords over tcp/ip. Setting up Bluetooth/Sockets is fairly easy once you understand the api calls. Let me know if you need more assistance.

Answer (score 0):

use C++ code to controll the pointer location. SetCursorpos(x,y).Enjoy